# Получаю undefined вместо числа

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```js
var coinsProfit = {
  "etf_china": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "red_etf_china": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "etf_america": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "red_etf_america": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "bitcoin": {
    "plus": 2000,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "red_bitcoin": {
    "plus": 2000,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "dollar": {
    "plus": 60,
    "minus": -200
  },
  "red_dollar": {
    "plus": 60,
    "minus": -200
  },
  "eu": {
    "plus": 80,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "red_eu": {
    "plus": 80,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "gbr": {
    "plus": 555,
    "minus": -20
  },
  "red_gbr": {
    "plus": 555,
    "minus": -20
  },
  "rub": {
    "plus": 666,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "red_rub": {
    "plus": 666,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "yen": {
    "plus": 222,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "red_yen": {
    "plus": 222,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "etf_gold": {
    "plus": 777,
    "minus": -35
  },
  "red_etf_gold": {
    "plus": 777,
    "minus": -35
  },
  "etf_IT": {
    "plus": 888,
    "minus": -11
  },
  "red_etf_IT": {
    "plus": 888,
    "minus": -11
  },
  "etf_usa": {
    "plus": 73,
    "minus": -88
  },
  "red_etf_usa": {
    "plus": 73,
    "minus": -88
  },
  "etf_japan": {
    "plus": 200,
    "minus": -98
  },
  "red_etf_japan": {
    "plus": 200,
    "minus": -98
  }
};
var coinsDataList = Object.keys(this.coinsProfit);

function plus(coinRandom) {
  getEquelsCoin(coinRandom);
};

function minus(coinRandom) {
  getEquelsCoin(coinRandom, 'minus');
};

function getEquelsCoin(coinRandom, sign = 'plus') {
  for (var key in coinsProfit) {
    if (key == coinRandom) {
      coinsProfit[key].plus;
      if (sign == 'plus') {
        return coinsProfit[key].plus;
      } else {
        return coinsProfit[key].minus;
      }
    }
  }
};
let count = 0;
coinRandom = coinsDataList[Math.floor(Math.random() * coinsDataList.length)];
count += plus(coinRandom);
```

UPD: Если в функцию записать

```
console.log(coinsProfit[coinRandom].plus);
return coinsProfit[coinRandom].plus;
```

То выводится число, сама же функция в момент вызова почему-то возвращает undefined.

Comment: Где определена функция plus?

Comment: Где у вас переменная `coinsDataList` и функция `plus`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, добавил: забыл скопировать.

Comment: Теперь расскажите нам, что за ошибка? Текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос. И вы не ответили, что за переменная `coinsDataList`?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function getEquelsCoin (coinRandom, sign = 'plus') {
        return coinsProfit[coinRandom] ? coinsProfit[coinRandom][sign] : undefined;
    };
```

если 2 аргумент не передаш в `getEquelsCoin` то будет то что по умолчанию

Comment: Видимо, ошибка в отсутствии return была. sign, кстати, так не сработает.

Comment: Поправьте, и я отмечу как правильный.

Comment: опечатка вышла надо  coinsProfit[coinRandom][sign]

Comment: Почему функция `minus`  ничего не возвращает?

Comment: ну ее не будет с такой реализацией потмоучто дял рлюса и минуса будет 1 функция getEquelsCoin такчто minusваще не нужен

Comment: Хорошо бы в ответе это как-то указать.

Comment: просто удалил и все

Answer (score 3):

У вас было несколько ошибок. Самая главная ошибка, вы забыли `return`.

Посмотрите пример с комментариями.

```js
var coinsProfit = {
  "etf_china": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "red_etf_china": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "etf_america": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "red_etf_america": {
    "plus": 100,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "bitcoin": {
    "plus": 2000,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "red_bitcoin": {
    "plus": 2000,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "dollar": {
    "plus": 60,
    "minus": -200
  },
  "red_dollar": {
    "plus": 60,
    "minus": -200
  },
  "eu": {
    "plus": 80,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "red_eu": {
    "plus": 80,
    "minus": -40
  },
  "gbr": {
    "plus": 555,
    "minus": -20
  },
  "red_gbr": {
    "plus": 555,
    "minus": -20
  },
  "rub": {
    "plus": 666,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "red_rub": {
    "plus": 666,
    "minus": -50
  },
  "yen": {
    "plus": 222,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "red_yen": {
    "plus": 222,
    "minus": -30
  },
  "etf_gold": {
    "plus": 777,
    "minus": -35
  },
  "red_etf_gold": {
    "plus": 777,
    "minus": -35
  },
  "etf_IT": {
    "plus": 888,
    "minus": -11
  },
  "red_etf_IT": {
    "plus": 888,
    "minus": -11
  },
  "etf_usa": {
    "plus": 73,
    "minus": -88
  },
  "red_etf_usa": {
    "plus": 73,
    "minus": -88
  },
  "etf_japan": {
    "plus": 200,
    "minus": -98
  },
  "red_etf_japan": {
    "plus": 200,
    "minus": -98
  }
};
var coinsDataList = Object.keys(this.coinsProfit);

function plus(coinRandom) {
  return getEquelsCoin(coinRandom); // Не было слова return
};

function minus(coinRandom) {
  return getEquelsCoin(coinRandom, 'minus'); // Не было слова return
};

function getEquelsCoin(coinRandom, sign = 'plus') {
  if (coinsProfit[coinRandom])
    return coinsProfit[coinRandom][sign];
  else
    throw new Error(`${coinRandom} not found`);
};
let count = 0;
coinRandom = coinsDataList[Math.floor(Math.random() * coinsDataList.length)];
console.log(plus(coinRandom))
```